# Destination URL for completed DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign SOAP API to create and send envelopes (insurance application forms) with one or two signers. 
I want the first signer to land on a specific url when signing is complete and the second signer to land on a different url when their signing (and therefore the entire envelope) is complete.

I can set a Destination URL in my brand for "Signing Completed" but that's at the signer level for all signers.

Is there a way to specify a landing page/url which the user can be redirected to when all signers have completed signing?

Comment: Do you have a specific need to use the DocuSign SOAP api. The DocuSign [Rest api](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/) has more features and better documentation.

Comment: Well the SOAP documentation couldn't be any worse. Migrating to Rest would mean rebuilding my integration, it ain't broke etc. but yes, I may have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specify a routingOrder for each recipient and set the appropriate URL for the recipient in the final routing order.

Once the final recipient sign, the user will be redirected to the URL.

Related API [RequestSenderToken](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/RequestSenderToken.htm)

Comment: This would work but it seems to be limited to in session signing. I can't see anything in the docs around setting a return url per recipient?

Comment: Only an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) can be redirected to a Sender Specified URL after signing. Remote recipients cannot be redirected. Remote recipients will start and finish within DocuSign.